# A confused substitution in integration

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

$$ F_{T_{k+1}}(t)= \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1}\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(T_k+t_{k+1} \leq t)$$

$$ = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(T_k+t_{k+1} \leq t \; \vert \; t_{k+1} = s) f_{t_{k+1}} (s)\text{d}s$$

$$ = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{t-s} f_{T_k}(r)\text{d}r f_{t_{k+1}}(s)\text{d}s$$

$$ = \int_0^t \int_0^r f_{T_k}(r-s)f_{t_{k+1}}(s)\text{d}s \; \text{d}r \hspace{4mm}\text{(the inner integral is called the convolution.)} $$

Hi, I would like to know how the last line was deduced from the previous one?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Do you know a formula for $f_{T_k}$ or $f_{t_{k+1}}$. Are they density functions?

Comment: $f_{T_{k}}(t)=\frac{\lambda^{k}}{(k-1) !} t^{k-1} e^{-\lambda t}, \quad t \geq 0$,

Comment: $f_{t_{i}}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}, \quad t \geq 0, i \geq 1$

Comment: Please use mathjax